# using shared preferences to store user name

Tags: java

I have a class to help me with handling back end requests; in this class I have a line to resolve my user object and also store the username locally:

```
public class BackEndHelper {
....
public static void Post_Login_async(user_username_pass_obj obj, final Context context) {
...
      user_obj userObj = utilsJson.getUser_when_SignInUp(response.body().string(), context);
}
....
}
```

In the *utilsJson.getUser_when_SignInUp* I have the line to save the username:

```
public static void Write2SharedPref(Context context, user_obj userObj) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString("username", userObj.getUsername())
            .apply();
}
```

the above method breaks even if username is not null. My plan is to read this then in my MainActivity:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString("token", null);
```

Would you please let me know if my local read/write is ok to store some variables?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong in your code above. What is user_obj? Can you check if the issue is on userObj.getUsername() method?

Comment: user_obj is ok. Is it ok to run this from static method though?

Comment: @ alexscmar you are right, the code is OK, I made some silly mistake somewhere irrelevant to this, I would put your answer as comment if you right it as answer . Thanks